# Why cant an osgi reference be declared as static datatype?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I am creating an osgi component like this:

```
@Component (configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL, immediate = true)
public class MyServiceAccessor
{
    @Reference (bind = "bindCluster", unbind = "unbindCluster", policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC, cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY)
    private static Cluster cluster;
```

I am getting the below message in log:

```
 395 !ENTRY com.test.eventrecovery 4 0 2021-09-08 10:32:32.559
    396 !MESSAGE [com.test.eventrecovery.MyServiceAccessor(265)] Field cluster in component class com.test.eventrecovery.MyServiceAccessor must not be static
```

When we were using felix annotations for @Component, @Reference we did not face this issue.
I am seeing this when we move to OSGI annotations.
Is there any specific reason for this behaviour? Please advise.
Also, I am unable to access the official OSGI documentation, which is adding to my woes. :(
http://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html - This link doesn't open.

Comment: I defer to the correct answer to @bjhargrave. Just want to add that this question indicates a very fundamental misunderstanding of OSGi components, and more in general, the value of OSGi. OSGi is _instance_ based, never ever static. Therefore, you can run an OSGi framework in an OSGi framework ad nauseaum. Allowing statics would kill this very fundamental feature. Removing all non-constant statics tend to  seriously improve a code base. Statics might look handy but they are the corrosion of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components instances are objects and thus all references are injected into instance fields. Not static fields. Since there can be multiple instances of a component, allowing injection into static fields would be problematic.

Try https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Now I understand. I'll redo the code to refrain from using statics.